# How do you pass configuration values to a directive

Tags: angularjs

I need to display multiple timers on a page. The following code is good so far, but its making the assumption that each timer will start with 1 hour. When the user refreshes the page, this will all be destroyed. So, I will save the start time in a database when a timer begins. When I gather that data again, I am not sure how I will pass the remaining seconds to the directive.

```
$scope.counter = 60*60
```

This will not always be true, but I'm not sure how to pass for example, a value of 1200 into the directive. Perhaps, if I load all the dom elements first, I can somehow get the time remaining from an attribute?

timer.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TimerController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.timers = [];
    $scope.Math = window.Math;

}).directive('timer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', 
    template: '<h5>{{Math.floor(counter/3600)}} hours {{Math.floor(counter/60)-Math.floor(counter/3600)*60}} minutes {{counter-Math.floor(counter/60)*60}} </h5>',
    controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
      $scope.counter = 60*60 //this needs to be dynamic...basically

      var callback = function() {
        $scope.counter--;
        $timeout(callback, 1000);
      };

      $timeout(callback, 1000);
    }
  };
});
```

html

```
<button ng-click="timers.push(1)">Add timer</button>
<div class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="timer in timers track by $index">
        <timer></timer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not seeing any reason to use a controller here. Directive controllers are primarily used for directive-to-directive communication. You could / should just use a `link` function

Answer (score 1):

You can always simply use attributes

```
<timer counter="1200"></timer>
```

and in your controller

```
controller: function($scope, $attrs, $timeout) {
    $scope.counter = parseInt($attrs.counter, 10) || 3600;

    // etc
}
```

---

If an isolate scope is ok for your directive, you can also use

```
scope: {
    counter: '@'
},
controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.counter = parseInt($scope.counter, 10) || 3600;

    // etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was very simple! I really should spend some time and read the Angular documentation.